# Почему не работает toggle jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть кнопка, оформлена в html следующим образом:

```
<p class="call-btn slide-btn">Заказать звонок</p>
```

Есть окно с классом ".popup_slide", которое в идеале должно "выезжать" слева при нажатии на кнопку. Проблема заключается в том, что при загрузке страницы кнопка убирается. В чем может быть дело, почему так происходит и какое тут решение проблемы?

```
$(".slide-btn").toggle(
        function() {  
            $(".popup_slide").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);  
        },
        function() {  
            $(".popup_slide").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);  
        }
    );
```

Стили для .popup_slide:

```
background: white;
margin: 0 auto; 
top: 0;
left: 0;    
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
z-index: 2001;
```

Comment: а какие стили у вас заданы для  .popup_slide ?

Comment: @Arsen добавил в пост. Тут вопрос сейчас даже не в .popup_slide, а в том, почему при добавлении этого jquery кода кнопка .slide-btn скрывается, хотя она должна быть лишь переключателем и jquery должен повесить на нее событие, с самой кнопкой при этом ничего не делая

Comment: какая версия jquery используется?

Comment: @Grundy версия 3.1.1